# How to filldown (forward fill) a filtered dataframe column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Problem Statement: Need to filldown a filtered dataframe.

I have a large dataframe. It is not shown here but I have included a dummy dataframe as an example below.
The only Status/State combinations I want are UP/GOOD and DOWN/BAD.
My dataset currently has undesired DOWN/GOOD combination and I'm trying to correct it to DOWN/BAD by filling down a filtered dataframe. Please advise on the code below, it is not working. There are couple of other solutions to this problem but I would like the filldown (.ffill) method.

Thanks!

Unfiltered dataset

[image]

Filtered Dataset: Down status shown

[image]

Desired Solution

[image]

Code:

```
"""This is a dummy dataframe"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dummydata=[["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Down","Bad"],["Up","Good"],
           ["Down","Good"],["Down","Good"],["Down","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],
           ["Down","Bad"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(dummydata, columns=['Status','State'])
filt=df['Status']=="Down"
df2=df.loc[filt]
df2.loc[df2['State']=='Good','State']=""
df2.loc[df2.State=='','State']= np.nan
df2.loc[df2['State']=='','State']=df2['State'].ffill()
print(df,df2)
```

My current filldown method is not working. Code is provided. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for slicing here.

The most simple would be to do:

```
df2['State'] = df2['State'].replace('Good', np.nan).ffill()
```

Output:

```
   Status State
3    Down   Bad
5    Down   Bad
6    Down   Bad
7    Down   Bad
10   Down   Bad
```

Comment: Can we just not use **df2['State'] = df2['State'].replace('Good', 'Bad')** ?

Comment: @The6thSense not if the first value is a Good, but for the provided example yes, or even `df2['State'] = 'Bad'` ;)

Comment: Thanks, mozway. Appreciate the help. I will review the other suggesting below as well. I am now starting out on my pandas journey :)

Comment: You're welcome @user17236057, welcome in the pandas' world, this is a great library ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
df.loc[df['Status']=='Down','State']='Bad'
df[df['Status']=='Down']

   Status State
3    Down   Bad
5    Down   Bad
6    Down   Bad
7    Down   Bad
10   Down   Bad
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly filter them using condition and assign them.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dummydata=[["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Down","Bad"],["Up","Good"],
        ["Down","Good"],["Down","Good"],["Down","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],
        ["Down","Bad"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"],["Up","Good"]]
df=pd.DataFrame(dummydata, columns=['Status','State'])
#Filter Status == Down and State == Good
df.loc[((df["Status"] == "Down") &  (df["State"] =="Good")), "State"] = "Bad"
```